# Import Amazon txt dataset into Neo4j

Tags: import, neo4j, cypher

I am fairly new to Neo4j and until now just loaded some csv files. 
Now I am trying to load the Amazon "Product co-purchasing network" dataset from:
https://snap.stanford.edu/data/#amazon

More precisely this one:
https://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon-meta.html
I am wondering what is the correct way to load this file?

The file is a simple text file, where products are separated by an empty new line. So it looks like this:

```
Id:   1
ASIN: 0827229534
  title: Patterns of Preaching: A Sermon Sampler
  group: Book
  salesrank: 396585
  similar: 5  0804215715  156101074X  0687023955  0687074231  082721619X
  categories: 2
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & 
Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Preaching[12368]
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Sermons[12370]
  reviews: total: 2  downloaded: 2  avg rating: 5
    2000-7-28  cutomer: A2JW67OY8U6HHK  rating: 5  votes:  10  helpful:   9
    2003-12-14  cutomer: A2VE83MZF98ITY  rating: 5  votes:   6  helpful:   5

Id:   2
ASIN: 0738700797
...
```

So far I tried to load it like a normal txt file

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///data/amazon-meta.txt" AS line
Return line
Skip 2
limit 10
```

The code returns the data in the following format:

```
["Id: 1"]
["ASIN: 0827229534"]
[" title: Patterns of Preaching: A Sermon Sampler"]
[" group: Book"]
[" salesrank: 396585"]
[" similar: 5 0804215715 156101074X 0687023955 0687074231 082721619X"]
[" categories: 2"]
[" |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Preaching[12368]"]
[" |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Religion & Spirituality[22]|Christianity[12290]|Clergy[12360]|Sermons[12370]"]
[" reviews: total: 2 downloaded: 2 avg rating: 5"]
[" 2000-7-28 cutomer: A2JW67OY8U6HHK rating: 5 votes: 10 helpful: 9"]
[" 2003-12-14 cutomer: A2VE83MZF98ITY rating: 5 votes: 6 helpful: 5"]
["Id: 2"]
["ASIN: 0738700797"]
```

So my next thought was to just merge all the lines from "id" to the next "id" together, but I am not sure if this is even possible or a good solution, since it seems quite complicated.

What would be a good way to load this dataset?

Comment: I don't think you can load this type of file format. This is not a valid CSV format.

Comment: I would suggest using python or some other language to process this file and convert it into a valid csv file. Then load into neo4j using LOAD CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the input. 
I used Python to convert the structure into a valid CSV one.